# PropertyModel Expression's Exception : org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: No get method defined for class:

Tags: java, wicket

I used `PropertyModel` as the part of my `DropDownChoice` as following:

```
    List<String> choices = Arrays.asList(new String[] { "Library", "School Office", "Science Dept" });
    String selected = "Library";

    DropDownChoice<String> serviceDDC = 
            new DropDownChoice<String>("service",  new PropertyModel(this, "choices.0"), choices);
```

Somehow I've got this exception thown:

```
caused by: org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: No get method defined for class: class com.samoo.tool.pages.CreatePrintingJob expression: choices
    at org.apache.wicket.util.lang.PropertyResolver.getGetAndSetter(PropertyResolver.java:481)
    at org.apache.wicket.util.lang.PropertyResolver.getObjectAndGetSetter(PropertyResolver.java:332)
    at org.apache.wicket.util.lang.PropertyResolver.getObjectAndGetSetter(PropertyResolver.java:242)
    at org.apache.wicket.util.lang.PropertyResolver.getValue(PropertyResolver.java:95)
    at org.apache.wicket.model.AbstractPropertyModel.getObject(AbstractPropertyModel.java:130)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.getDefaultModelObject(Component.java:1724)

....
```

I know that there's something wrong with the expression. I've been trying different parameter inputs but it still doesn't work. Could anyone help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you're using `PropertyModel(this, "choices.0")`, Wicket is trying to find a property named `choices` via reflection through a method `getChoices()` of the class declaring the PropertyModel. This method doesn't seem to exist in `com.samoo.tool.pages.CreatePrintingJob`, as the exception is stating.

Also, if that `0` is an index, you should be accessing it with the `[index]` expression, as this JIRA issue suggests: [PropertyModel does not support index only property ("[0]")](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WICKET-2354)

However, it seems you want to initialize the `DropDownChoice` to the first element of `choices`. But What Wicket will do if you set the DropDownChoice's Model to `PropertyModel(this, "choices.[0"])` will be mapping the selection of this DropDownChoice in the following way:

- At form rendering time to present the (pre)selected choice, it will use the first element in the `choices` list.
- At form submission time to store the user selected value, it will store the selection in the first position of the `choices` list.

Summarising, the backing object representing the `DropDownChoice`'s selection would be the first element in the `choices` list.

So, you'll probably want to use a whole different Model, independent from the choices list, for the backing object representing the DDC's selection.

```
List<String> choices = Arrays.asList(new String[] { "Library", "School Office", 
       "Science Dept" });
String selected = "Library";
IModel dropdownModel = new Model<String>(choices[0]);
DropDownChoice<String> serviceDDC = 
        new DropDownChoice<String>("service",  dropdownModel, choices);
```

You might find the following links useful:

- [Using the DropDownChoice component](http://wicket.apache.org/learn/examples/dropdownchoice.html)
- [Working with Wicket Models](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Working+with+Wicket+models)

Answer (score 1):

you are declaring choices inside the method, in order to get the PropertyModel to work you need to declare it on a class level not on a method level. As @Xavi López pointed out the espression is not corret you nedd to use choices.[0]

Comment: Don't forget about the misconception that probably is using an element of the list of choices as the DDC's Model, which probably is the real issue here.

Answer (score 0):

It is good idea to use `IModel` instead of `PropertyMOdel`.`PropertyModel` has big problems in refactoring. In my cases I did it and the problems solved properly.Also I have override the `toString()` of my `Topic` object.

```
topicDropDown = new DropDownChoice<Topic>("topicOptions", new IModel<Topic>() {
        @Override
        public Topic getObject() {
            return top;
        }

        @Override
        public void setObject(Topic t) {
            top = t;
        }

        @Override
        public void detach() {
        }
    }, new LoadableDetachableModel<List<Topic>>() {
        @Override
        protected List<Topic> load() {

            List<Topic> topics = top.getAllTopics();
            return topics;

        }
    });
```

Comment: It may late.Thanks god that erimerturk found his answer